# Ignore character in Regex Python?

Tags: python, regex, wildcard

I want to find all phone numbers that start with a "0" and are followed by 10 digits.

`r1=re.search('^[0]+\d{10}',i)`

However, some of them are written as "01-234-567-8-90", which technically is a 0 followed by 10 digits, but it has dashes in it. When I run a Regex search command, it doesn't recognise it.

Is there a way to tell regex to ignore certain characters, such as " " and "-"?

Comment: The `*` is a typo, please remove.

Comment: You probably meant to use `re.search(r'(?<!\d)0(?:-?\d){10}(?!\d)',i)`. Or, `r'^0(?:-?\d){10}$'`. What do you mean by "find"? Where are you looking for the match(es)?

Comment: Are you limited strictly to one `re.search` or are you allowed to preprocess text using `python`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you very much, it works. Quick question: I don't understand the placing of the brackets () in the statement, specifically: 
Why do we do ...```0(?:-?\d){10}```... as opposed to  ...```0(?:-?)\d{10}```....
In other words, why do we include the ```\d``` in the brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.search(r'0(?:-?\d){10}',i)
```

The regex pattern matches

- `0` - a zero digit
- `(?:-?\d){10}` - a non-capturing group that matches 10 consecutive occurrences of

  - `-?` - an optional hyphen
  - `\d` - a digit.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0QB0EE/1).

If you do not want other digits to appear on both ends of the match add numeric boundaries:

```py
(?<!\d)0(?:-?\d){10}(?!\d)
```

The `(?<!\d)` lookbehind makes sure there is no digit on the left, and `(?!\d)` lookahead makes sure there is no digit on the right, so we match numbers that are 11 digits long

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's better methods, but you could just remove the hyphens before the regex search.

```
i.replace('-', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to validate it, you can remove "-" like

```
phone_number_without_hyphens = phone.replace("-", "")
```

then check it by regex

```
re.search('^[0]+\d*{10}', phone_number_without_hyphens)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
^[0(?:+44)][ -]?\d[ -]?\d[ -]?\d[ -]?\d[ -]?\d[ -]?\d[ -]?\d[ -]?\d[ -]?\d[ -]?\d$
```

or
^[0(?:+44)](?:[ -]?\d){10}$ cleaner

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).